# Insert query result into table and print timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following code

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM am_user_status
WHERE product_id = '11' AND STATUS = '1';
INSERT INTO metric_results(DATE)
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

I have two columns 'Active Mag Subscribers' & 'Date'

So far the query prints the date into the date column but not the query result which would look like unless I remove the insert date query.

I think I'm formatting it incorrectly.

Help much appreciated cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert the active subscribers count and current timestamp into the table, the following `INSERT INTO` with `SELECT` work:

```
INSERT INTO metric_results (`Active Mag Subscribers`, `DATE`)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Active`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS `DATE`
FROM am_user_status
WHERE product_id = '11' AND STATUS = '1';
```

Please find more examples using [INSERT INTO](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/)